# Bind a onKeyDown to a particular webview android

Tags: java, android

Hey I am working on implementing the back key functionality for my WebViews. I have got it working with the given code but the problem is I need it to work for 3 different WebViews so none conflict with each other and cause a crash, so far it works for each one singly at a time. My guess is I need to bind the keylistener to that particular webview but I am unsure how. Here is the code I am using for my youtube view for example..

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    wv_yt = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_youtube);

    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if (wv_yt.canGoBack() == true) {
                wv_yt.goBack();

            } else {
                finish();
            }
            return true;

        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: you have 3 different WebViews on the screen at the same time, and you want to to keep a back stack of sites visited for each one?

Comment: no its three separate webviews on different pages but I just need to be able to bind the ketlistener to a particular webview so its only called when that webview registeres a onKeyDown if that makes since